# Display of arrays in pgAdmin

Tags: arrays, postgresql, pgadmin-4

One of the columns of my table has a type of an array of integers. Most of the the times its values in PGAdmin are displayed as:

[image]

However, sometimes I see [0:1] in front of the array as below:

[image]

As per what I found browsing Google, [0:1] indicates the dimensions of an array.

Question: why sometimes it is displayed differently? Above screenshots correspond to the same column.

Comment: Report this bug here https://redmine.postgresql.org/projects/pgadmin4

Comment: @n33rma how do you know that this is a bug?

Comment: Because clearly this is not expected return value from Postgres :)

Use psql and check ...

Comment: Have you tried with the latest version of pgAdmin4 (v4.2)? If not I would suggest try with it https://www.pgadmin.org/download/, from the screenshot it looks like you have older version of pgAdmin4.

Comment: Updated to v4.2, same behaviour.